# Populate Listview with Sharedpreferences

Tags: android-listview, sharedpreferences

In my app, I have one listview with one string "Add New String". When user selects this, then Alert dialog prompts with one edit text and button. User has to write name of new String in this box and when user clicks on button that must be added to original list. Till this I have done. but my problem is when user closes this app, and restarts, then that new added string is not there in List. I have to do this with shared preference.How can it be done with it? Here is my code.

### MainActivity .java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    String add[]=new String[]{"Add new List"}; 
    final private static int DIALOG_LOGIN = 1;
    ArrayList<String> arr1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;

    ArrayList<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;

    int count = 0;
    int i=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, add);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter1);
        //onLoad();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String data = lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                if(data == "Add new List")
                {
                     count = count + 1;
                     showDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);
                }
            }
        });

    }


      @Override
     protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
      {

      AlertDialog dialogDetails = null;

      switch (id)
      {
        case DIALOG_LOGIN:
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialogbuilder.setView(dialogview);
        dialogDetails = dialogbuilder.create();
        break;
      }

      return dialogDetails;
     }

    @Override
     protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {

      switch (id) {
      case DIALOG_LOGIN:
       final AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
       Button btnOk = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
       final EditText etList = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.etList);


       btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(etList.length() <= 0)
            {
                etList.requestFocus();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Name of List", 1000).show();
            }
            else
            {
                String name = etList.getText().toString();
                String newName[] = new String[]{};

                if(arr2.contains("Add new List"))
                {

                    arr2.add(name);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + name , 1000).show();
                    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr2);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter2);
                    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    etList.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + count, 1000).show();

                    dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);
                }
                else
                {
                    arr2.add("Add new List");
                    arr2.add(name);
                    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr2);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter2);
                    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    etList.setText("");
                    dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);
                }
                }
    }
    });

       break;
      }
     }  

    }
```

## activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/etHint" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/etList"
        android:text="@string/ok" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save data to shared preferences from your `btnOk`'s `onClick()` method. you can save data before `arr2.add(name);` line in your `onClick()` method.

**usage of shared preferences.**

To obtain shared preferences,

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To edit and save preferences,

```
String myString = "TextHere";
prefs.edit().putString("com.example.app.myValue", myString).commit();
```

To read preference,

```
String myValue= "com.example.app.myValue";

// use a default value using ""
String s = prefs.getString(myValue, "");
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But I am new to this concept. Can you explain with simple example?

Comment: @AnilBhatiya Follow this [tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/androidstream/sharedpreferences-tutorial). you cam learn about `SharedPreferences` from it.